# Errors when running sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.3 with Java 11

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, java-11, sonarcloud

In my [Android application project](https://github.com/EventFahrplan/EventFahrplan) I am using the `sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.3` with OpenJDK 11. When I run `./gradlew sonarqube` the following is output to the console. It hasn’t been there ever since. It might be new since I use Java 11.

Here is my SonarQube configuration: [sonarqube.gradle](https://github.com/EventFahrplan/EventFahrplan/blob/master/gradle/sonarqube.gradle)

```
> Task :buildSrc:jar
:jar: No valid plugin descriptors were found in META-INF/gradle-plugins
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Task :app:sonarqube
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve interfaces org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve interfaces org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve interfaces org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(1462) Type java.lang.String is indirectly referenced from required .class files but cannot be resolved since the declaring package java.lang exported from module java.base conflicts with a package accessible from module <unnamed>
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve declared methods org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Unable to run check class org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor -  on file 'src/main/java/nerd/tuxmobil/fahrplan/congress/net/CustomHttpClient.java', To help improve the SonarSource Java Analyzer, please report this problem to SonarSource: see https://community.sonarsource.com/
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(324) The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemHandler.handle(ProblemHandler.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemHandler.handle(ProblemHandler.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.handle(ProblemReporter.java:2646)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.ProblemReporter.isClassPathCorrect(ProblemReporter.java:5117)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromCompoundName(LookupEnvironment.java:1791)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromConstantPoolName(LookupEnvironment.java:1821)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:517)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:1036)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:308)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedAnnotationBinding.resolve(UnresolvedAnnotationBinding.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedAnnotationBinding.getAnnotationType(UnresolvedAnnotationBinding.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.DefaultBindingResolver.getAnnotationInstance(DefaultBindingResolver.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodBinding.getParameterAnnotations(MethodBinding.java:170)
        at org.sonar.java.model.JUtils.parameterAnnotations(JUtils.java:275)
        at org.sonar.java.se.checks.NonNullSetToNullCheck$PreStatementVisitor.checkNullArgument(NonNullSetToNullCheck.java:237)
        at org.sonar.java.se.checks.NonNullSetToNullCheck$PreStatementVisitor.checkNullArguments(NonNullSetToNullCheck.java:230)
        at org.sonar.java.se.checks.NonNullSetToNullCheck$PreStatementVisitor.visitMethodInvocation(NonNullSetToNullCheck.java:219)
        at org.sonar.java.model.expression.MethodInvocationTreeImpl.accept(MethodInvocationTreeImpl.java:100)
        at org.sonar.java.se.checks.NonNullSetToNullCheck.checkPreStatement(NonNullSetToNullCheck.java:87)
        at org.sonar.java.se.CheckerDispatcher.executeCheckPreStatement(CheckerDispatcher.java:62)
        at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visit(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:633)
        at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.execute(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:263)
        at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:219)
        at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.execute(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:75)
        at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.visitNode(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:65)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:100)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:125)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:102)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:125)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:102)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:83)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:69)
        at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.scanFile(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:55)
        at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.lambda$runScanner$0(VisitorsBridge.java:151)
        at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.runScanner(VisitorsBridge.java:156)
        at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.runScanner(VisitorsBridge.java:151)
        at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:134)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:104)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.lambda$scan$1(JavaAstScanner.java:79)
        at org.sonar.java.model.JParserConfig$FileByFile.parse(JParserConfig.java:225)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:77)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.scanAndMeasureTask(JavaFrontend.java:175)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaFrontend.scan(JavaFrontend.java:127)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSensor.execute(JavaSensor.java:109)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:45)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:75)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:66)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:68)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:109)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:447)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:443)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:401)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:109)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:128)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:109)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:58)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:52)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy425.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:102)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:502)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:487)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:470)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:106)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:271)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:105)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:98)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:92)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution$2.withWorkspace(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
...
```

`sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.2.0` behaves the same.

Comment: Are you running this on a container ? If so what is your base image ?

Comment: I can confirm that I have also been getting these long exceptions while running the SonarQube plugin 3.3 using Gradle 7.0+, on local `Windows machine(with OpenJDK 11 and Android Studio defualt JRE)` and on Azure hosted agent(Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with Adopt OpenJDK 11.0.11+9). The official docs say to `build` project, `set JDK 11 path` and then run `gradlew sonarqube` task, which also doesn't help much.

Comment: I had also posted this problem on [Sonar Community forum](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-analysis-for-android-project-with-java-11/54208) but I could not get any feedback as to what seems to be the problem for this JDK 8 to 11 migration.
Is it because the `Android 31.jar` has `java.lang` package compiled with Java 8 and the same package is available in JDK 11 as well?

Comment: @JJD, were you able to fix/find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @Jay Not really. You can add `property "sonar.java.jdkHome", "/some/path/to/java-8-openjdk-amd64"` to your configuration. But you might not want to check the machine-specific path into version control. It would be great if the path could be read from an environment variable or such.

Answer (score 1):

### Shot in the dark - are you using an alpine base container

As mentioned in your question, you have moved to openJDK 11. There were issues with a lot of software when I upgraded to openJDK 11 when using alpine as the base container. The alpine base container worked fine for Oracle JDK 8, but when the solution was migrated  to openJDK 11, software that was previously working, started having execution and runtime issues as it could not work properly with the openJDK 11 install.

Found out that Alpine Linux is using `musl-libc` for its libc, where most other flavours of Linux use `glibc`, GNU's C library. Moved to ubuntu and centos container base images and all my previous applications worked fine with openJDK 11. Standard Linux software built on non-Alpine flavours, normally get linked against `glibc` and thus cannot be executed successfully with Alpine, without installing a `glibc` compatiblity layer, which is not simple.

The reason that alpine was used previously was for its lightweigt size. Currently there is no resolution for alpine, unless you seek an alpine-openJDK11 container. That versions out there cannot be used in our environment as they are not official and maintained, thus the use of ubuntu and centos.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, GNOME 3.36.8, Wayland on my local machine. I cannot tell what SonarQube is running on their servers.

Comment: OK - Have you tried stepping down a version of the plugin, just in case there is a bug related to openJDK 11, try 3.2 to start with ?

Comment: How do I accept you edits on teh answer ?

Comment: Same with `org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.2.0` - a lot of `AbortCompilation` errors.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have posted a question on [sonarqube as well](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/errors-when-running-sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3-3-with-java-11/51816) which is where I got the details you upgraded from JDK 8 to 11.

There have been many changes from JDK 8 to 11 some of which are quite significant. One thing that comes to my mind is maybe the SonarQube plugin or your code is using a module that has not been defined via `add-modules`,`uses-modules`, `open-modules` or `opens-modules`.

Sniffing through your code I didn't find `module-info.java` files so that might be causing the issue - specially if the SonarQube plugin is using reflection to access those `unnamed` modules.

Also one of the error lines states this:

```
Status ERROR: org.eclipse.jdt.core code=4 Could not retrieve interfaces org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.AbortCompilation: Pb(1462) Type java.lang.String is indirectly referenced from required .class files but cannot be resolved since the declaring package java.lang exported from module java.base conflicts with a package accessible from module <unnamed>
```

Which leads me to believe it's related to the JDK 9 modules feature.

The docs are here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-7BB28E4D-99B3-4078-BDC4-FC24180CE82B

Here is a good guide for JDK 9 Modularity (which is when it was introduced):
https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity#adding-modules-to-the-unnamed-module

Comment: Yes, I had to upgrade from JDK 8 to 11 because the Android Gradle Plugin 7+ requires it. With regards to `unnamed` modules I would expect that the SonarQube Gradle plugin takes care of sorting this out because the error message only occurs when it runs - not during a "normal" build.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to resolve the errors?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with your code base and don't have much time to dig into 
 it so I wouldn't be able to help you much. However you could check these links which might point you to a solution 
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/java-analyzer-compile-error-after-upgrading-to-openjdk11/20760.